# Existance of solution to integral Fredholm equation

Tags: operator-theory, functional-equations, spectral-theory, integral-equations

I am a bit confused with the existence/non existence of a solution to the following equation:
$$\int_{-T}^{T} R(t,\tau) x(\tau) d\tau = y(t), \forall t\in [-T,T]$$
where $y(t)=C$ (a constant function), $x(\tau)$ is the unknown function, and
$$R(t,\tau)=1-\frac{\left|{t-\tau}\right|}{a}$$
What bothers me is that I've proven that this equation has a solution, and on the contrary I've proven (by another way) that it doesn't! And I don't find the mistake. If you could help me find the mistake, I would appreciate it.

Proof that this equation does not have a solution (if $C\neq 0$):

By contradiction, suppose there is a solution to $\int_{-T}^{T} \left(1-\frac{\left|{t-\tau}\right|}{a}\right) x(\tau) d\tau = C, \forall t\in [-T,T]$. Take a derivative (of both sides) with respect to $t$ and get:
$$\int_{-T}^{T} \frac{(-1)}{a}sgn(t-\tau)x(\tau)d\tau=0, \forall t\in [-T,T]. $$
Which can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{(-1)}{a}\int_{-T}^t x(\tau)d\tau +  \frac{1}{a}\int_{t}^T x(\tau)d\tau=0, \forall t\in [-T,T]$$
Take another derivative with respect to $t$ to get: $\frac{(-2)}{a}x(t)=0$, which means that $x$ is the zero function. But that solution does not satisfy the equation.
$$$$

Proof that this equation has a solution:

The operator $x\longmapsto \int_{-T}^{T} R(t,\tau) x(\tau) d\tau$ is a compact $\left[ \text{Fredholm's theory}\right]$ and self-adjoint (since $R(t,\tau)=R(\tau,t)$), and therefore there is an orthonormal basis $\left\{\psi_k(t)\right\}$ of eigenvectors of this operator. Denote the eigenvalues by $\left\{\lambda_k\right\}$. There is no eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ because the only solution to the equation  $\int_{-T}^{T} R(t,\tau) x(\tau) d\tau=0$ is the zero function $x(t)=0$ (see the proof above for the non-existance of solution for $y(t)=C\neq 0$).

As $\left\{\psi_k(t)\right\}$ is an orthonormal basis, we can expand every function $y(t)$ (even the constant function $y(t)=C$) to $y(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \beta_k \psi_k(t)$ where $\beta_k=\int_{-T}^{T} y(t) \psi_k^*(t) dt$. The following function is then the solution of the equation:

$$x(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\beta_k}{\lambda_k} \psi_k(t)$$

To see that we substitute it:
$$\int_{-T}^{T} R(t,\tau)x(\tau)d\tau = \int_{-T}^{T} R(t,\tau)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\beta_k}{\lambda_k} \psi_k(\tau)d\tau = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\beta_k}{\lambda_k} \int_{-T}^{T} R(t,\tau)\psi_k(\tau)d\tau = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\beta_k}{\lambda_k} \lambda_k \psi_k(t) = y(t)$$

Now, there are many places where my proof is not precise, for example, I am not sure that the series I gave for $x(t)$ converge, but what is the $real$ reason for one of these proofs to fail? And which one is wrong?

Comment: Your first proof assumes your solution $x$ is continuous, which is probably too strong an assumption.

Comment: @Jason, I don't think that this is the reason for the proof to fail. The differentiation under the integral sign (Leibniz integral rule) can be applied even if the functions are not continuous, under much more general conditions (like measure theoretic). For instance, if $x(t)$ is in $L^1([-T,T])$ then we can still apply it. See here for instance:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement

Comment: Differentiation under the integral sign is fine - it's the second step which fails. That is, you do not necessarily have $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-T}^tx(\tau)\ d\tau=x(t)$ if $x$ is not continuous. It seems that with a little more care you can still show $x=0$, however; we have $\int_{-T}^tx(\tau)\ d\tau=\int_t^Tx(\tau)\ d\tau$ for all $t\in(-T,T)$, so $\int_{-T}^tx(\tau)\ d\tau=\frac12\int_{-T}^Tx(\tau)\ d\tau$ is constant. Hence $x=0$ a.e. This would suggest your first solution is correct.

Comment: So where does the second solution fail?